# Creating a dynamic cascading menu in Angular

Tags: angular

I created a dynamic menu that has three levels

I want this menu to work in a cascading way but unfortunately when I click on the menu all the menus open.
Also when I click on the menu all levels open together

Help me please

```
  showitems=false;

   fullMenu = [
    {name:"Home",childs:[
       {name:"HomeLevel-1",childs:[
         {name:"Home-level-2"}
        ]}
     ]},
    { name:"about",},
    {name:"register",childs:[
      {name:"registerLevel-1",childs:[
       {name:"registerLevel-2"}
      ]}
    ]},
  ]

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  showSubMenu(){
    let menu = this.fullMenu;
    menu.forEach(data => {
      if (data.childs) {
        this.showitems = !this.showitems;
      }
    });
  }
```

```
<ul>
    <li class="item" (click)="showSubMenu()" *ngFor="let menu of fullMenu" >
        {{ menu.name }}
                <ul *ngIf="menu.childs ? showitems : '' ">
                    <li class="item" *ngFor="let submenu of menu.childs">
                        {{ submenu.name }}
                        <ul *ngIf="submenu.childs">
                            <li  class="item" *ngFor="let submenu_2 of submenu.childs">
                                {{ submenu_2.name }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: If possible first go with displaying all parents property. Then if menu option is clicked then just returned data of that clicked index only.. this way you can keep track

Comment: yes with displaying all parents property

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution utilizing bootstrap.  The trick here is recursive templates.  Utilizing recursion allows each "node" to expand/collapse independently.

`[attr.data-target]` and `[attr.id]` were used to dynamically create id's, which is what allows the bootstrap utility to determine the elements to trigger.

I ran this with bootstrap 4.4.1.  Hope it helps!

```
fullMenu = [{
    name: "Home",
    childs: [{
      name: "HomeLevel-1",
      childs: [{
        name: "Home-level-2"
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "about"
  },
  {
    name: "register",
    childs: [{
      name: "registerLevel-1",
      childs: [{
        name: "registerLevel-2"
      }]
    }]
  }
];


<ul>
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-fullMenu let-level="level">
    <li *ngFor="let item of fullMenu; let i = index">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#foo' + i + level" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        {{item.name}}
      </button> {{i }}


      <ul *ngIf="item.childs && item.childs.length > 0">

        <div class="collapse" [attr.id]="'foo' + i +level">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.childs, level: level + i + fullMenu.length }"></ng-container>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: fullMenu, level: 0 }"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for time and response, but i want a something like angular material table. means similar to that but for the menus. that means make a component for menu so i can use it in different project.

Comment: see link please: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular

Comment: then put the code in a dumb component and use the input bindings to make it reusable.  Please look into dumb/smart components for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do the same and facing some issue though with help of Stackoverflow i found my answer. Please check if this helps you. This is kind of reusable component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6zee7

This still has some css issue which i need to fix.

Comment: ekbatan5111374@gmail.com

Comment: @saeed-moradi Please check now i have updated stackblitz link